# What combination of events could lead to a comprehensive denazification program in modern Austria?

Tags: warfare, politics, geopolitics

TLDR version: How can I write a believable piece of fiction in which Austria is being de-nazified in 2020 and later?

Long version follows.

**Historical background**

In 1938, Nazi Germany annexed Austria during the so-called [Anschluss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss). This happened without any meaningful resistance from the Austrians because the majority of them embraced Nazi values. However, it was possible to spin it as if Austria was a victim of the Germans. This was officially reflected in the [Moscow declaration of 1943](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Declarations#Declaration_on_Austria) in which the Allies declared Austria the first victim of Hitler.

Austria was neither the first (truly first victim of Nazi Germany was Czechoslovakia), nor a victim (most Austrians supported Hitler). However, Austrian politicians heavily used that declaration for about 46 years in order to avoid responsibility for the crimes that the Austrians committed together with the Germans during World War II. This was called the [Victim theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_theory). For 46 years the Austrians denied any complicity in Nazi crimes.

As a result, ordinary Austrians were never denazified (as opposed to Germans).

On July 8th, 1991, the Austrian chancellor Franz Vranitzky, admitted the guilt of the Austrians in the Nazi crimes in a speech before the parliament (see [Austria-Forum.org](https://austria-forum.org/af/Wissenssammlungen/Essays/Zeitgeschichte/Verantwortung_%C3%96sterreichs) and [protocols of the Austrian parliament](https://www.parlament.gv.at/PAKT/VHG/XVIII/NRSITZ/NRSITZ_00035/imfname_142026.pdf), pp. 15 and 16 for the original German text). From this speech you can conclude that the victim theory is wrong.

**Fiction part**

Imagine I want to write a story, in which Austria starts to denazify itself in 2020.

Question: How could this happen

- despite the fact that Austrian government admitted that the victim theory is wrong thirty years ago and nothing happened and
- given the fact that in order to be believable it must happen as a result of pressure (Vranitzky held this speech in the aftermath of the [Waldheim scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Waldheim) and it probably would not have happened otherwise)

?

**Possible answer 1: Russia, Ukraine and/or other ex-USSR country**

The USSR suffered losses of

- 8.7-10 million dead soldiers,
- 5.7 million captured soldiers,
- 6.5 million Soviet citizens who were brought to Germany and enslaved there

according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Front_(World_War_II)#Casualties), plus probably the largest number of civilian casualties.

To this day, Russia and Ukraine suffer from gender disbalance (much more women than men) that was caused by World War II.

These casualties are the result of purposeful actions on the side of the Nazis ([war of annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_annihilation)) and did not happened by accident or unfortunate combination of events.

Since at least one Austrian official admitted that the Austrians are co-responsible for the Nazi crimes, it would be reasonable for the ex-Soviets (Russians, Ukrainians and others) to demand some sort of punishment to the Austrians.

Why didn't they?

A believable explanation is that in 1991 (when Vranitzky admitted that Austrians were as guilty in the Nazi crimes as the Germans) the Soviet Union was about to collapse. In 1992 and thereafter, Russians and Ukrainians were busy rebuilding their economies and adapting to a new reality.

There are three options how ex-USSR countries can decide they want to put pressure on Austria.

**Option 1**: At a certain point in time, Russia and Ukraine experience a period of stability and prosperity which is long enough for their elites to start digging in history (contrary to 1991 when everything was falling apart and they had more urgent needs).

In addition to that, both countries become more and more Westernized, thus a) more exposed to Western social media (like this subreddit) and b) travel to Austria more frequenty and are more likely to learn about its history.

At some point, enough Russians/Ukrainians learn about Austrian complicity in the crimes against their ancestors and demand actions from its government.

**Option 2**: Like option 1, but this time Russians and Ukrainians put economic pressure on Austria by not travelling there and not buying Austrian products.

**Option 3**: Opposite of option 1. Things are bad in Russia/Ukraine and some of their politicians want to put blame on foreign powers.

**Option 4**: Benevolent elites get to power in both Russia and Ukraine and want to end the conflict in Eastern Ukraine. How can you (e. g. Russia) make peace with your former enemy (e. g. Ukraine)? By finding a third party (e. g. Austria) who wronged both of you and wiggled itself out of responsibility.

**Possible answer 2: Israel**

Because the victim theory is declared wrong by Vranitzky, we can say that the Austrians are also responsible for the Holocaust.

I see two options to make Israel put enough pressure on Austria.

- **Option 1:** The Israelis learn just how antisemitic modern Austria is. Officially, Austria condemns Holocaust, but when you talk with educated, well-to-do people you run a chance of at least 30 % of running into a Holocaust denier, anti-Semite, or someone who think tha the Austrians did not do anything wrong (based on my own observations and experiences). Something (like an economic downturn and rise of anti-Semitism) could make those hidden aversions come to light and make the Israelis realize how anti-Semitic many Austrians are.
- **Option 2:** Semi-apocalyptic scenario. Let's assume that the US becomes weaker and, as a consequence, cannot support Israel like it does now. Being surrounded by adversaries, Israel needs funding from someone else. So, it turns to the EU and offers them two options. First, the EU provides support to Israel and helps it defend itself against its neighbors. In exchange, Israel keeps its mouth shut. Second, EU does not support Israel. Then, Israel mobilizes all its resources to show the world that by having Austria as its member, the EU tolerates unremoreseful Nazis. In the worst case, this can lead to Austria leaving the EU (or being forced out of it). Then it would be a second Brexit (which may be followed by other members leaving). The EU gives in and forces Austria to undergo a comprehensive denazification program (and if it doesn't, the EU will impose sanctions like it did in [2000](https://www.politico.eu/article/hungary-eu-news-article-7-vote-poland-rule-of-law/)).

**Possible answer 3: US**

Let's assume that there is plenty of Russians, Ukrainians, and Jews in the US. If enough of them write to their senators, the US could put Austria under pressure.

**Possible answer 4: Popular videogame**

Note: This is IMHO the least believable of all scenarios, even for fiction (for any person who knows even a little about Austria and its people).

There is this video game, [World of Tanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Tanks) developed by Belarussians who were hit by the Nazis (incl. the Austrians) as much as the Russians and Ukrainians.

Theoretically, someone like them could create a successful game which would re-educate Austrian gamers. A generation of people who are aware of the fact that their ancestors were unremorseful war criminals grows up. The old generation slowly dies. Provided that the game is popular enough over a couple of decades, it could denazify the Austrians as good (or even better) than a state-driven program.

**Possible answer 4: All of the above**

Are there any other options that I missed?

Comment: (1) Most Austrians acquiesced the union with Germany because they considered themselves German. Nazi ideology had nothing to do with it. Austria and Germany are two separate countries only because Woodrow Wilson, President of the USA and Emperor of the World, explicitly decreed so. (Among other visionary decrees of the same statesman we can count pushing Slovenia and Croatia into Yugoslavia and arranging a shotgun marriage between Czechia and Slovakia.) (2) I don't see how the skewed sex ratio of Russia and Ukraine (only after 40 or 50) can be attributed to a war which ended 75 years ago.

Comment: ... And it is not clear whom exactly you want to denazify. The overwhelming majority of people who were adults in 1945 are dead and buried. Do you want to denazify people who were one year old in 1945?

Comment: You seem to be asking a Politics question. Politics is hard to predict and twists and turns in funny ways, so in fiction you can have it come out any way you wish. Here, that means the question is likely Opinion-Based.

Comment: I get deNazification in 1946.  There were people who had been in the Nazi party and they were moved out of positions of power.  Like DeBaathification in Iraq after the Iraq war.  But what does deNazification in 2020 even mean?   Getting right wing conservatives to admit they are wrong?

Comment: VTC --- ***PLEASE*** read the [tour] and [help] of a Stack Exchange community before you ask a question! However interesting your query might be, writing questions are off topic here. *"How can I write a believable piece of fiction..."* -- we're here to help you create your fictional world or setting, not how to write your story.

Comment: This belongs on either Writing.SE or Politics.SE, not on Worldbuilding.SE. Also, I tend to agree with AlexP; Austria never really was a Nazi country, and there isn't really anybody left alive *to* de-nazify.

Answer (score 1):

**Austrian election.**

The people of Austria vote.  Parties espousing right wing theories are less attractive to the voters than parties espousing alternative approaches that promote unity of all Austrians as citizens of the world, and tolerance and compassion for the suffering of those less fortunate.

Once in power these liberal forces consolidate by putting in place policies that promote equity and employment.  School curricula are changed and history is cast in a different light, to change the mindset of the young.  These young people are openly scornful of right wing demagogues who are seen as stale and silly.

Austria is a democracy, and there will always be people who find solace and strength in different ideas, including dated and intolerant ideas.  If competing ideas can be made more attractive, factions like this will have fewer new recruits and the old ones will eventually die out.

These issues are on American minds too.

Comment: Given that Austria *currently* has a nationalist government (along with Poland, Hungary and Italy), and populist/nationalist movements like Brexit or the *Mouvement des gilets jaunes* are also growing, you might want to reconsider. Voters are voting their self interest, which is currently not aligned with the political classes of Europe or North America.

Comment: @Thucydides - I agree it is unlikely to happen.  But it is more likely that Austrian voters will change their government than it is the USSR rises again and does it for them.

Comment: Indeed. The point, however is that they voters will choose what they believe will benefit themselves the most. the answer speaks of ideas of tolerance, etc., but it is quite clear across the Western world voters are no longer buying this. Even Brazil has elected a nationalist government. The Austrians may eventually elect a new government with a non nationalist character, but only if they believe the long term effects of the platform will be beneficial to themselves.

Comment: @Willk, like the Confederate statues controversy in the US

Answer (score 0):

**Somebody points out that all the perpetrators are 93 years or older, and owning up to Nazism is now relatively painless.**

The **denazification** was mainly the removal of officials, civil servants, company administrators, etc. from their positions of authority. That means doing it now will make little difference to Austria today. Take the files of everybody who was 18 years old at the date of the German surrender, check if he was in the armed forces or some position of authority, and if so look if there is any indication of Nazi-inspired **actions** before that date.

Your story might look different if there was a serious attempt to **judge dead people** for their actions during WWII (a bureaucratic nightmare) or to **judge post-war actions and voiced opinions** like supporting the FPÖ (which would raise interesting questions on what is and isn't a nazi policy).

Your best chance is to abandon any thought of realism and to write a [Kafkaesque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka#%22Kafkaesque%22).